# How can I prevent angular from validating a form when certain buttons are clicked?

Tags: angularjs

Angular seems to be firing validation messages when ANY button within form $scope is clicked. Is there a directive that can be applied to a `<button>` that will prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All  elements are considered to be of type submit by default.

use this to prevent form submissions:

```
<button type="button">
```